# How to setup a custom local domain name for a Node app similar to laravel valet?

Tags: node.js, laravel, valet

I use Laravel valet as my local server and with that, it takes my project folder names and uses them as local domain names. So if I make a folder called test-website, I can now access that in the browser by going to test-website.test.

Starting up a node app, the only way I can access the app in the browser is by going to localhost::3000. That's fine and it works but I'd much rather a custom domain name e.g. new-node-app.test. Is there any way to do this and even better, is there any program out there that can automate this like Laravel Valet does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Laravel Valet to create a proxy.

```
valet proxy [--secure] [--] <domain> <host>
```

so you could do something like this to make `https://node.test` work as expected.

```
valet proxy --secure node.test http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

Note: proxies are forwarding requests to an existing service. So do not point your proxy to `https://127.0.0.1:3000` unless you are already serving https.

Works with subdomains too. So if you were running a socket server, you may prefer to use subdomain of `io` or something.

```
valet proxy --secure io.mydomain.test http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

to verify you have the correct configuration. You can list proxies using `valet proxies` or delete a proxy by using `valet unproxy`

Comment: Beautiful!  So glad they added this

Comment: i've tried and doest work. in valet list its already directly , after command also its say already. ```Valet will now proxy [http://yogi-aw.test] traffic to [http://localhost:3000].
Restarting nginx...```

Answer (score 2):

**NEW ANSWER:**

Use Valet proxy. In your terminal: `valet proxy your.node.domain http://localhost:3000/`

**OLD ANSWER:**

Say you want your domain name to be `node.test`. You have to create a file named `node.conf` in `~/.valet/Nginx` (or `~/.config/valet/Nginx` in newer versions). 
node.conf :

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    "text/html"                 epoch;
    "text/html; charset=utf-8"  epoch;
    default                     off;
}

server {
    listen          80;             # the port nginx is listening on
    server_name     node.test;    # setup your domain here

    gzip            on;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    location / {
        expires $expires;

        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout          1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000; # set the adress of the Node.js instance here
    }
}
```

and then `valet restart`.

source: [Valet Github: is it possible to share node.js program running on port 3000](https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/523#issuecomment-410879531)

Answer (score 1):

Okay I actually just worked it out myself.. haha

So in the hosts file I added:

```
127.0.0.1:80 nodeapp.localhost
```

Going to that address works and doesn't seem to conflict with my Laravel Valet domains.

To note I did try using the extension .test which is what I use for Laravel Valet websites but that didn't work for obvious reasons.